# Materialised View to be created on a view

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am new to oracle and i wanted to know if materialized views can be created on top of views. I also need a column in the mview that has a complex calculation for which I am thinking of writing a function.

Comment: Yes, you can create a materialized view over a review. I have no idea what you need, require, or have tried regarding the function to populate a column. Please share examples and what code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are materialised views, and then again there are materialised views.

By which I mean that the capabilities of the materialised view can vary greatly with respect to query rewrite and refreshability according to the exact nature of the tables (or views) that it references, and according to their properties.

So although you might be able to create an MV that references a view, whether it is useful to you or not is a matter that depends on a great many other issues.

I find that the documentation can sometimes be unclear, particularly in edge-cases, and the best approach is generally to create the MV and then to test its capabilities using Oracle built-in procedures -- here's a link to DBMS_MView for 10.2 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#CEGGEHHC

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just had a small question: Is it possible to call a user defined function inside the materialised view or is it just the select statement i can use ?

Comment: If it's a deterministic function, then quite possibly, but it could be even minor version-dependent. It's unlikely that query rewrite would work, I'd think.

Comment: Hi again. I created the materialized view on a view (test_view) which is refering to base table (test_table1 & test_table2). Could you please help me on to how to create the incremental refresh on insert/update/delete to the first table test_table1 ? I created materialized view logs on both the tables but the updated data is only reflecting in the complete refresh.

Comment: execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('test_mview2', 'C', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE); statement is working fine.. but execute DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('test_mview2', 'F', '', TRUE, FALSE, 0,0,0,FALSE, FALSE); statement is not working.. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Start by adding the names of the parameters to that procedure call, and ask it as a new question, and define what you mean by "is not working"

Comment: I saw this procedure here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/refresh.htm#DWHSG8366 .. When i say it is not working it means that even after inserting a new record in the underlying table and running the procedure, the change is not reflected in the materialized view.